# mongodb using update to avoid race condition, update error when field is an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here is my collection :

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        id: {type: Number, ref: 'id'},
        member_id: Number,
        title: String,
        content: String,
        pros: String,
        cons: String,
        createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        vote: [{
            member_id:{type: Number,unique: true},
            support: Boolean,
            voted: Boolean, 
            createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
        }],
        comment: [{
            member_id: Number,
            support: Boolean,
            content:String,
            createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
        }]
    });
```

This db is for record the votes from users. In server side, receive post to accumulate votes:

```
Topic.update({"id":id,"vote.member_id":member_id},  
        {$set:{ 'vote.$.member_id' : member_id, 'vote.$.support' : vote_to,'vote.$.voted' : true}} , { upsert: true }, function(err,test){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.json({error: true});
        }
        else{
            console.log(test);
            res.json({msg:"success vote"});
        }
```

But in the initial situation, in the other word, no entry in vote (vote is []), It receive an error message:
`{ [MongoError: Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.',
  code: 16650,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 133,
  ok: 1 }`

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation It is not recommended to use the positional operator ($) in mongoDB with upsert...

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

> Do not use the positional operator $ with upsert operations because
>   inserts will use the $ as a field name in the inserted document.

So remove the `upsert: true` in your update command and see if it works.
I recommend that you check updated count in the callback of update and if it is zero then you can send another update request with [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) in vote array.